# Spring MVC junit

Tags: spring, maven, model-view-controller, junit4

I have created sample spring MVC application structure is given below.

```
abc.war-|
    |src/main/resourecs -> dispatcher-servlet.xml and framework-context.xml
    |src/main/webapp ->WEB-INF --|-->views --> all view pages.
                                 |---web.xml
```

This below project is dependent in above project.

```
xyz.jar-|
    |src/main/java ->| All Java Controller class is here.
    |src/main/resources -->| other Application Context.xml files are here.
```

Now my question is how to write Junit for controller and under which project? Both project built in Maven.

Comment: Unit tests should generally live with the code they test.  As to how to write them, what problem(s) are you having?

Comment: as explained above my controller class is inside xyz.jar and configurations files (web.xml,dispatcher-servlet.xml and applicationContext.xml) are under war file then how to write junit for my controller class whether i have to keep my controllerTest class under "abc" or under "xyz".and i want use Annotation and execute junit using SpringJunitRunner

Comment: You wouldn't use those context files for a unit test.  Unit test should be small and isolated.  http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html  Look into mocking framework such as mockito http://mockito.org/ Spring also provides things like mock requests http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html

Comment: But internally i am reffering these classes in my source code which beans are defined in other xml.

Comment: You would use a test context and mock some of the collaborators

Comment: Thanks All for prompt reply, i solved my problem,